# QTableWidget random load inefficient - C++

Tags: c++, qt

My function `loadRandomly()` is very inefficient, with a 20x15 it takes about 3-4 seconds.
in `MyTableWidget` constructor I set `srand((unsigned)time(0))`

I dont understand why its so slow also if I don't reallocate QTableWidgetItems if already exists.

```
void MyTableWidget::loadRandomly()
{
    for(int i=0; i<this->rowCount(); i++)
        for(int j=0; j<this->columnCount(); j++){
            int randomN = minNum + (int)rand()/((int)RAND_MAX/(maxNum-minNum));
            if(!item(i,j)){
                setItem(i,j, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(randomN)));
                qDebug() << "MyTableWidget::loadRandomly() item created at " << i << " " << j;
            }
            else
                item(i,j)->setText(QString::number(randomN));
        }
}
```

Comment: I saw a thread here about creating `QTableWidgetItem` takes a lot of time, in short it's better to use `QTableView` that will handle all optimization for you. And console output takes a lot of time too, so without `qDebug()` performance will be much better

Comment: What is the output: How many reallocation are done? Is it still slow if you don't do any allocation at all, just for test? (comment the line `setItem...`

Comment: Seriously, what line of this code fragment consuming a lot of time? Can you comment them one by one to know what cause performance problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had a look at the [Qt Implementation](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/itemviews/qtablewidget.cpp) (Qt 4.8)

[Constructing an item](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/itemviews/qtablewidget.cpp#line1290) is straightforward, and does not take any time.

However, [*inserting an item*](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/gui/itemviews/qtablewidget.cpp#line155) seems **overly** time consuming, at a glance, *in the case `view->isSortingEnabled()` is true*.

So I would suggest trying to call `setSortingEnabled(false)` at the beginning of the method, then `setSortingEnabled(true)` at the end (if necessary).

After checking the documentation, I realize that they actually give the same advice:

> If you want to set several items of a particular row (say, by calling setItem() in a loop), you may want to turn off sorting before doing so, and turn it back on afterwards; this will allow you to use the same row argument for all items in the same row (i.e. setItem() will not move the row).

### Edit

I cannot reproduce the issue. Try the following minimal compilable example (MCE) and tell me what's the output. If it is much more than a few milliseconds, then it means there's something wrong with your configuration. If it is less than a few milliseconds, it means there's something wrong somewhere else in your code: try to nail down the problem by deleting little by little part of your code, until the problem disappears (it will eventually, since your code will converge to the MCE that doesn't reproduce the problem).

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "MyTableWidget.h"

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // layout
    QVBoxLayout * layout = new QVBoxLayout();
    
    // button
    QPushButton * button = new QPushButton("Load randomly");
    layout->addWidget(button);
    
    // table widget
    int numRow = 20;
    int numCol = 15;
    MyTableWidget * table = new MyTableWidget(numRow, numCol);
    layout->addWidget(table);

    // clicking on button load the table
    QObject::connect( button, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                table, SLOT(loadRandomly()) );

    // exec application
    QWidget * w = new QWidget();
    w->setLayout(layout);
    w->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**MyTableWidget.h**

```
#include <QtGui>

class MyTableWidget: public QTableWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyTableWidget(int r, int c) : QTableWidget(r, c) {}
        
public slots:
    void loadRandomly()
    {
        QElapsedTimer timer;
        timer.start();
        
        int minNum = 1;
        int maxNum = 99;
        for(int i=0; i<rowCount(); i++)
        for(int j=0; j<columnCount(); j++)
        {
            int randomN = minNum + (int)rand()/((int)RAND_MAX/(maxNum-minNum));
            if(!item(i,j))
            {
                setItem(i,j, new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(randomN)));
                qDebug() << "item created at " << i << " " << j;
            }
            else
                item(i,j)->setText(QString::number(randomN));
        }
        
        qDebug() << "The slow operation took" << timer.elapsed() << "milliseconds";
    }
};
```

**output**

first click:

```
item created at  0   0
// ...
item created at  19   14 
The slow operation took 5 milliseconds
```

second click:

```
The slow operation took 1 milliseconds
```

**Potential issue with your code**

You've connected some signals of the table widget to some other slots, and executing these slots takes a lot of time (potentially indirectly, by triggering other slots that may repaint() the widget).

Comment: I turend off sorting and qDebug output but there's no visible changes. Im running in a i5 @1.8 Ghz

Comment: @user2458579 I suspect that you've connected a signal to a slot that call a `repaint()`, and that you have V_Sync enabled in your configuration (ie, each repaint() wait for monitor V_Blank) . If 20x15 repaint() are called in this case, at 60Hz, this would take 20 * 15 * 16.66ms = 5 seconds. Hence, make a research in your code for `repaint()`, and replace it by `update()` if any.